# Unable to recieve data, from Intent in new activity.

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-activity

Well, as I mentioned in heading, I can't get data from one activity, to another. I am making a really simple RSS reader, that loads data asynchroously, sends them to listview and opens the selected article in new activity's webview. And the problem is, that when i try to start an activity with webview, a can't pass data from the main activity. 
So here is what I am doing:

1) In first activity (Main activity), i get data from my listview element, that user clicks on:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
        News clicked = (News) adapter.getItem(arg2);
        String clickedTitle = clicked.title;
        String clickedLink = clicked.link;

        System.out.println("Title: " + clickedTitle + " / LINK: " + clickedLink);  /*Here I can see my data in logs -> they are correct at this moment*/

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OpenFullArticle.class);
        intent.putExtra(clickedTitle, "clickedTitle");
        intent.putExtra(clickedLink, "clickedLink");
        startActivity(intent);
        } 
});
```

So for now everything is okey, but than, when a new activity is started (OpenFullArticle activity), I am doing this:

```
public class OpenFullArticle extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_full_article);

        String title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("clickedTitle");
        String link = getIntent().getStringExtra("clickedLink");


        System.out.println(title); //Tried link too, simultaneous each one - both ar null
    }
```

So I'm stuck for this moment and have no idea, what I'm doing wrong. Tried debuger, checked the Intent, and it hadn't extras there, that I added in first activity. 
Maybe you can give me a clue, what could cause such a strange issue.

P.S. If it's necessary, I can provide a full code or a full project in github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code in first activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OpenFullArticle.class);
            intent.putExtra( "clickedTitle",clickedTitle);
            intent.putExtra("clickedLink", clickedLink, );
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
intent.putExtra("clickedTitle", clickedTitle); 
// the first pram is the key
// the second is the value
intent.putExtra("clickedLink", clickedLink);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)

Also use `Log` instead of `System.out.println`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in this line:

```
intent.putExtra(clickedTitle, "clickedTitle");
intent.putExtra(clickedLink, "clickedLink");
```

You need to give key first and then the value:

```
intent.putExtra("clickedTitle", clickedTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
intent.putExtra(clickedTitle, "clickedTitle");
        intent.putExtra(clickedLink, "clickedLink");
```

with

```
intent.putExtra("clickedTitle",clickedTitle);
        intent.putExtra("clickedLink",clickedLink);
```

Comment: Oh my god! Seems that coding for a 13 hours without stop made my brains to lag. 
I'm really sorry, for such a noobiuos question, but I was unable to resolve it by myself. 
Thanks for help!

P.S. Strange is, that Eclipse didn't recognize it as a syntaxis mistake, or it shouldn't?

Comment: It's not a syntax error. Either key or value is a string. And clickedLink, clickedTitle are strings in your case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your first activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OpenFullArticle.class);
    intent.putExtra( "clickedTitle",clickedTitle);
    intent.putExtra("clickedLink", clickedLink, );
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially try to isolate the issue by passing some hardcoded values to extras

like 
intent.putExtra("id",1);
intent.putExtra("name","abc");

and check whether OpenFullArticle  activity has the extras.